# Importing rules for PMD Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pmd

I'm installing Eclipse Juno for Java Developers for a class, and we've been asked to install the PMD plugin.  We have our own xml file with the rules and we have to replace the default rules for the plugin. When I browse and select the file, the import tool doesn't allow me to press 'ok'.

Any suggestions? I'm pretty new to this stuff.

Comment: This is not a coding question.

Comment: @gkovacs90 but it is about a development tool which is on topic

Answer (score 6):

It's a problem with the plugin 4, try with 3. Import your rules and you can after that do an update to 4.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set it in the Eclipse configuration of PMD: `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `PMD` -> `Rules Configuration` -> `Import Rules Set`

Before you can do this the PMD plug-in itself must be installed: `Help` -> `Eclipse Marketplace...` -> Search for PMD, install it and restart eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

`Right click on project` - > `properties` -> `PMD` -> check `Enable PMD` -> click on radio button `Use the ruleset configuration in project file` -> `Browse` -> select your custom pmd xml file